# ReactJS app properly handling input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everything seems to work on my todo list except when I type my task and hit the submit button to add a task I get `cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class Todo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: 'Simple React TODO list',
      count: 0,
      tasks: ['just', 'simple', 'thing']
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleClickIndex = this.handleClickIndex.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(event){
    eval(this[event.target.name]).bind(this)(event)
  }
  handleClickIndex(index, event){
    eval(this[event.target.name]).bind(this)(index, event)
  }
  handleChange(event){
    eval(this[event.target.name]).bind(this)(event)
  }
  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    eval(this[event.target.name]).bind(this)(event)
  }
  task(event) {
    this.setState({task:event.target.value})
  }
  addTask(event) {
    if (!this.state.task) return
    const tasks = this.state.tasks || []
    tasks.push(this.state.task)
    this.setState({tasks:tasks, task:''})
  }
  removeTask(index, event) {
    const tasks = this.state.tasks
    tasks.splice(index, 1)    
    this.setState({tasks})
  }
  render(){
    const tasks = (this.state.tasks||[]).map((task,index)=>(
      <li>
        {task} <button name="removeTask" onClick={event=>this.handleClickIndex(index,event)}>x</button>
      </li>
    ))
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
        <div>
          <ol>
            {tasks}
            {
              this.state.task &&
              <li>{this.state.task}</li>
            }
          </ol>
          <div>
            <form name="sendTask" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input name="task" value={this.state.task} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
              <button type="submit" name="addTask" onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div style={{marginTop:'1rem'}}>
            <h5>Notes</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>See Angular 7 version <a href="https://codepen.io/mjunaidi/pen/VOpzga" target="_blank" title="Open in new tab">here</a></li>
              <li>See version 2.0 <a href="https://codepen.io/mjunaidi/pen/MZKZOZ" target="_blank" title="Open in new tab">here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(
  <Todo/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.3.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What are you using eval for? You can instead just call `this.addTask(event)`

Comment: why are so many people even bothering with bind in 2019? Just use closures when defining your functions and they will automatically be bound to the class instance. you can also declare your state directly in the class. you don't even need a `constructor` at all for this example.

Comment: You should use arrow function like `handleClick = event => { ... }` & `this` will automatically be binded in your functions.
The error is triggered because you haven't binded `this` in all your functions.

Answer (score 0):

why would you use eval? just call this.addTask. Your error is related to the fact that addTask is not defined, instead, you should refer to addTask function as this.addTask.

It is better to call this.addTask in handleClick function or pass addTask directly to the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need to use `eval`, I think at all, only in really punctual cases (But it's a bad practice), also you don't need all those `bind` statements, I've made a simple StacksBlitz with your code, you'll see that you can simplified a lot: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-simple-state-todo?file=index.js

Hope this help.